# Codeigniter phpbb ckeditor ckfinder integration

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, ckfinder

I tried to integrate codeigniter, phpbb forum, ckkeditor and ckfinder together and it works ok at localhost (local use php/nginx).

When i deploy on hosting (apache server), **ckfinder not working**.

My project's structure:

```
- system/
- application/
- forum/
- ...
- public/...
- public/ckeditor/
- public/ckfinder/
```

and my .htaccess file (at root folder):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|public|robots\.txt)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

When i try to select Choose Picture from the UI, it shows error at request: http://example.com/public/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=Init was not found. In the response, the error message is

```
'Trailing paths and PATH_INFO is not supported by phpBB 3.0'.
```

The above error message come frome phpbb forum (in startup.php file). The ckeditor (ckfinder) should not call validate path_info from phpbb forum, **maybe my .htaccess file is incorrect**. **Anyone please help me?** thanks.